# Do the HR think I'm stupid because I'm too old for an internship?

Tags: resume, internship

I'm 26 years old, wanting a CS internship, the reason I'm this old, is because I'm disabled, so I didn't start school at a young and didn't take full credits at university. But I don't meantion these things in my CV, nor I meantion my GPA.

I don't want them to know I'm disabled because most will refuse to give me an internship, and if they accept, it might be out of pity.

So when I send my CV, do they go: "Why does a 26 years old want an internship? He is so old, probably too stupid?"

Comment: It's hard to know what they would think. But regardless, if you want the internship, you should apply. You'll either get the call for an interview or you wont.

Comment: Pretty sure they'll notice you're disabled at an interview, as far as the pity goes, that's not your issue. Getting the internship is what you're after, how you get it is less important. If for once your disability works in your favour, then that's fine. I'm sure it's worked against you often enough to make up for that.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Also, why are you putting your age on your CV?

Comment: If Robert de Niro can become an intern, why shouldn't you?

Comment: I'm 26 at this moment too, and I'm currently having an internship as part of finalizing my school degree. I can tell you that they do NOT think you're stupid. There are many reasons that can result in a person starting their career at a later date. I know several people who finish their studies in their mid-30's. My current employer seemed to VERY impressed with me during the interview and was hired on the spot. Being older than the average person with your amount of experience means nothing. Experience and knowledge is what they will look at. Not age.

Comment: I switched careers and took a paid internship at age 46. My age was a plus -- employers realized I knew enough by then to show up to work on time and put in a full day. All they needed to teach me were the ins and outs of the specific area that you don't get in school.

Comment: I got a 12 month software engineering internship at a global pharmaceutical company in the UK at the age of 32.  Age should not be an issue.

Comment: @DJClayworth im from lebanon, and isn't it a must to include your birth date?

Comment: @Lynob No, absolutely not. Unless rules in your country are very different from any country I've worked in you should not put your birth date or age on a CV.

Comment: @Kilisi Not all disabilities are visible

Comment: @Kiwi Like what? What is not visible but is likely to have kept the OP out of work and Uni for a decade?

Comment: @Kilisi Depending on his situation or how bad it was/is it could have been anything from mental disorders to physical pain. You don't need to have a wheelchair, hearing aid, white cane, etc to be disabled. I will link 2 articles:
https://invisibledisabilities.org/what-is-an-invisible-disability/

http://www.disabled-world.com/disability/types/invisible/

Comment: @Kiwi I doubt very much any of those apply, but I see what you mean

Answer (score 11):

Why do you think 26 is too old for an internship?  Just for the record, I didn't get a BS until I was in my mid-30s, yet did an internship the last year or two (and worked for that company for several years after graduation).  A decade later, I went back for an MS, and wound up doing an internship with a very well-known research institute.

No one has ever asked my age when I was applying for internships (or jobs, FTM).  If you are good at what you do, ask your professors to recommend you for suitable places.  (That's how I got both of mine: I didn't even know the companies were looking until profs told me.)

Nor is the disability going to be a problem, if you are competent.  These days, it may even be a plus, since it helps the employer look good in diversity stats.

PS: This applies to the US, other countries may differ, of course.

Comment: In some regions companies don't *want* to know about disabilities of applicants to not get sued for breaking any anti-discrimination laws when they reject them for some reason completely unrelated to the disability.

Answer (score 3):

1) Why do you think they won't give you the internship, if your disability doesn't interfere with your ability to do the job?

2) Don't reject honest sympathy and a desire to help.

3) Not mentioning your GPA is going to be an issue. You need to give them a reason to believe that you are competent enough to be worth investing in; if you don't, they will skip to the candidate who does.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem. I have an illness, I was afraid I wouldn't get hired because I might be a liability. It is not true. If you are competent and show you want to learn and work hard, it won't matter.

Even if they don't hire you because of that, then why work there anyway (or be an intern). Just be honest, the worst thing you could do is lie about it and they find out.

Also you are never to young/old to start. I know people who have finally found out what they want to do (they are also 26 years old) and are currently attending school and doing internships.

I know people who have to go back to college and they are nearing 60.